# jQuery Blur and Submit propagation issue

Tags: jquery, blur

I have a simple new user form with a "Display Name" input field that triggers an ajax call on blur() event. This to verify if the entered value already exists in DB.

Example:

```
 $("#displayname").blur(function() {
    //do something
 })
```

Once the display name is given the user clicks the "Submit" button to proceed further, which is the next immediate action in the form.

Example:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
   $("#form").trigger("submit");
})
```

However, the blur() event ALWAYS triggers first and the button click is not registered. It's only on the second click on the button that propagation becomes correct. This is causing chaos in my form.

Is there any way for me to suppress blur() event of the text box WHEN I click the button?

Thank you for any kind of help
Cheers!

Comment: Maybe it's better if you suppress the click event (maybe disabling the button) until the blur function is done. What do you think?

Comment: Since blur (focusout) fires before click in all browsers, the only thing you can do is put the blur handler on a setTimeout and return early if the button was clicked.  But in general, it's a bad design.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the problem scenario is when the `blur` is caused by a button click.

Fortunately, the event info is passed to the handler, and the event should contain a `target` property.  From that, you can deduce whether to do something about the `blur`.  Use your favorite js debugger to stop in the `blur` event handler and see what's on the `target` property.

```
$("#displayname").blur(function(evt) {
   if (evt.target is not the button){ // figure this out with debugger
      //do something 

       return true; // I handled it
   }
   return false; // I didn't handle it
 })
```

However, in this scenario you won't do your dynamic checking that whatever is in the field is not in the database.

@eZakto has a good suggestion in disabling the submit button until the ajax check on your input is done.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Sorry that I replied late. We could not solve the problem through event.target either so the only method left was to push validation into java and get a callback.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for 'event.relatedTarget'.  For focusOut or blur events this is set to the element receiving focus, thus you know that you the blur is caused by a click on your submit button and not any other event.

```
$("#displayname").blur(function(event) {
    if (event.relatedTarget && (event.relatedTarget.id === 'button')){
        $("#button").trigger('click');
    }
    else {
        // do blur stuff here 
    }
});
```